# What does it effectively mean when the same unit is specified in Wants and Before?

Tags: systemd

Let's say a unit (Unit1) has the following unit file configuration:

```
[Unit]
Wants=Unit2
Before=Unit2
```

I read *Wants* as "Unit1, when started, will try to run Unit2 (but it's ok if it fails)".

I read *Before* as "Unit1 should be started before Unit2".

If the *Wants* makes Unit2 (try to) start before Unit1, but the *Before* makes Unit1 start before Unit2, what exactly is the reality? What happens here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=):

> If a unit `foo.service` contains a setting `Before=bar.service` and both units are being started, `bar.service`'s start-up is delayed until `foo.service` has finished starting up. Note that this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the requirement dependencies as configured by `Requires=`, `Wants=` or `BindsTo=`.

Note: independent and orthogonal.

[And](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Wants=):

> `Wants=`
>   A weaker version of `Requires=`. Units listed in this option will be started if the configuring unit is.

This says nothing about causing Unit2 to be started *before* Unit1. All it means is that when starting Unit1 is set to be started, Unit2 will be set to be started as well, but it doesn't mean that starting Unit2 will be finished before, after or while Unit1 is started. That ordering is set by `Before`, which will cause the startup of Unit2 to be delayed until Unit1 has finished starting up.

Comment: Makes total sense, thank you!